# Fetch and Replace href attribute value of <a> tag using prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, tapestry

I have a simple link inside my tml (apache tapestry specific) :

```
<a href="www.google.com" class="info-value" target="new">www.google.com</a>
```

Now on the browser if I am trying to click the link, actually it's redirecting to

`http://localhost:8080/..../..../www.google.com`

Instead of it should open a new tab for that link.

So the logic which I am thinking is :

```
1) Fire a javascript on page load
2) Get the href value of anchor tag 
3) Append http:// at the start, if it doesn't contains it.
```

So to do this, actually I want to use prototype (javascript framework), and I am bit new to this...

How can I write the function using the Prototype.js library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say where the value for your `href` is coming from. As you say you need to prepend an "http". Assuming the link is dynamically rendered, why don't you just do this server-side, probably much easier. In tml:

```
... href="${url}" ....
```

and in .java:

```
public String getUrl() {
  return "http://" + url;
}
```

This is a much better approach than doing it client-side as what happens if the user has javascript turned off?

On the other hand, if it's a static link in your .tml, just write "http://www.google.com"!

**Edit:** In light of your comment below:

```
public String getUrl() {

   if (!url.startsWith("http://") {
      url = "http://" + url;
   }

   return url;
}
```

The above is just an example of what do do. You can either add another method to `activityDetails` which does this (e.g `getExternalLinkWithProtocol()`), or provide a wrapper method similar to the one above.

Comment: +1 and yeah I can't imagine why this would need to be done on the client side unless the information is _only_ known on the client side. Otherwise it belongs on the server side in the .java file paired with the .tml file.

Comment: well actually the href="${activityDetails.externalLink}" - coming from the database, and that linkvalue may have the http:// or may be not... That's why I wanted to check it using javascript.

Comment: @Nirmal - see my edited answer. This really should be done serverside.

Answer (score 1):

No reason to do this on the client side.  Simply change your template to:

<a href="http://www.google.com" class="info-value" target="new">www.google.com</a>

and if it's based on a property:

<a href="http://${hostname}" class="info-value" target="new">${hostname}</a>

... adjust to fit your properties, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function(){
    var links = document.links;
    for(var i=links.length-1; i>=0; i--){
        var link = links[i];
        var href = link.getAttribute("href");
        if(href.indexOf("http://") < 0){
            link.href = "http://" + href;
        }
    }
};
```